# How to properly define a NuGet package for an assembly where the dll file name is different from the assembly name?

Tags: nuget

I had to package a portable version of Newtonsoft.Json as an internal NuGet package under a different name (`Newtonsoft.SL5.Json`). The reason is that we are building into a shared bin directory and I do not want the Silverlight version to overwrite the full .NET version. (Yes, we still have Silverlight and yes the portable Json.Net version is not good enough for non Silverlight code we have)

- The package file name is Newtonsoft.SL5.Json.8.0.1.19229.nupkg
- Inside it there is Newtonsoft.SL5.Json.nuspec
- Inside it there is lib\sl5\Newtonsoft.SL5.Json.dll

The nuspec file content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Newtonsoft.SL5.Json</id>
    <version>8.0.1.19229</version>
    <authors>Newtonsoft</authors>
    <owners>Newtonsoft</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Json.NET Portable .NET 4.0</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © James Newton-King 2008</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Now something I am doing wrong, because as a result, when adding the dependency in Visual Studio, the reference it produces is:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.SL5.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.SL5.Json.8.0.1.19229\lib\sl5\Newtonsoft.SL5.Json.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

And of course, there is no such assembly `Newtonsoft.SL5.Json`. It should be `Newtonsoft.Json`.

So, I am doing something wrong. How should I change the NuGet package so that it uses the correct assembly name, i.e. `Newtonsoft.Json`? Because even though I changed the file name, the assembly name is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

while adding reference IDE takes .dll files that are included in the package (lib/{platform}/). If you rename those files added and packaged in nupkg file -> those should be added in  element.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand your answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: if you have `\lib\sl5\Newtonsoft.SL5.Json.dll` in package then this file will be referenced in VS. Can you output different file name while packing?

Comment: No, I need it to be named this way to avoid collision with the non Silverlight version.